# OwlCarousel and bootstrap slide use in website

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new.when I'm using bootstrap slide show and owl-carousel then bootstrap slide show take owl-carousel **CSS** how to use that.

carousel item.

```
<div class="carousel">
    <div class="item1">
        <img src="images/item.png" >
    </div>
    <div class="item1">
        <img src="images/item.png" >
    </div>
    <div class="item1">
        <img src="images/item.png" >
    </div>
    <div class="item1">
        <img src="images/item.png" >
    </div>
    <div class="item1">
        <img src="images/item.png" >
    </div>
    <div class="item1">
        <img src="images/item.png" >
    </div>
</div>
```

bootstrap slide show

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="images/baner.png" alt="Chania">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/baner.png" alt="Chania" >
        </div>      
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/baner.png" alt="Flower" >
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/baner.png" alt="Flower" >
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe it depends in what order you are calling your steelsheets. Whithout any code it will be hard to help you.
In my projects I proceed this way

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="web/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="web/lib/owlcarousel/css/owl.carousel.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="web/lib/owlcarousel/css/owl.theme.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <!-- your bootstrap slider -->
    </div>

    <div>
        <!-- your owl slider -->
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="web/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="web/lib/owlcarousel/js/owl.carousel.js"></script>

    <!-- init owl -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.myOwlCarousel').owlCarousel({
            // some configs
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i'm using this but bootstrap image take class in owlCarousel and image take default width .